# Extraer Descripción de cuenta de twitter (no los twitter ni los nº de twitter) Scrapeando

Tags: python-2.7, data, beautifulsoup, twitter, scraping

Quiero extraer el texto que da una descripción de una cuenta de Twitter, pero no logro acceder, lo único que he logrado es extraer el número de seguidores, pero no logro saber cómo llegar al texto que describe la cuenta de Twitter.

Me imprime el número de seguidores, pero no logro imprimir la descripción.

Código:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

def obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
    url_google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}'.format(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
    respuesta = requests.get(url_google, headers=USER_AGENT)
    respuesta.raise_for_status()
    return termino_busqueda, respuesta.text

def procesar_resultados(html, palabra):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    resultados_encontrados = []
    bloque = soup.find_all("div", class_="g")
    for resultado in bloque:
        titulo = resultado.find('h3').string
        resultados_encontrados.append(titulo)
    return resultados_encontrados

def scrap(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
    palabra, html = obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
    resultados = procesar_resultados(html, palabra)
    return resultados

if __name__ == '__main__':
    palabra = 'Quantika14'
    h5 = (palabra, 1, "es")
h6 = (h5[0])



username=h6
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')



f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
title = f.find('a')['title']
print (title)

g=soup.find_all('title', limit=1)



h = soup.find('data-testid', {'UserDescription': 'textContent'})



title2 =g
print (title2)
title3=h
print(title3)
```

Esto es lo que sale cuando hago en el inspector la opción "Copy Selector"

```
#react-root > div > div > div > main > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-14lw9ot.r-1tlfku8.r-1ljd8xs.r-13l2t4g.r-1phboty.r-1jgb5lz.r-11wrixw.r-61z16t.r-1ye8kvj.r-13qz1uu.r-184en5c > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > span
```

y esto lo que sale cuando hago en el inspector copy outherHTML

```
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Damos soluciones a través de nuestras aplicaciones y peritajes informáticos. Encontramos a los autores de crímenes usando nuevas tecnologías.</span>
```

Con estos datos, en la página de Twitter, no logro extraer la Descripción usando BeautifulSoup, lo máximo que logro es None.

Comment: ¿Has considerado usar la API de Twitter?

Comment: No sabria decirte, me vendria bien un ejemplo o un enlace sobre su uso para esto

Comment: ¿La documentación de Twitter? Evita tomar a mal este comentario por favor :) Hice un par de bots usando la api de Twitter, está bien documentada. Inclusive hay librerías listas para usarse con python, los bots los hice desde cero. Ánimos, sí se puede :D

Comment: Ok, aun asi me viene bien mas informacion para esto que recurrir solo a la documentacion oficial.

Comment: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=python+twitter+api&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.4 revisa el tercer enlace, creo que es lo que buscas mi estimado :D

Comment: Gracias, he usado el enlace a documentación de BeautifulSoup y he logrado avances, pero aun así no logro la descripción de la cuenta, lo que si logro son los seguidores y el título de la cuenta.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

Comment: He añadido nuevo código, expongo el problema de forma concreta al final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tengo la solución, he tenido votos negativos por poca investigación, pero he logrado la respuesta, así que no veo puntuación negativa justificada.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

def obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
    url_google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}'.format(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
    respuesta = requests.get(url_google, headers=USER_AGENT)
    respuesta.raise_for_status()
    return termino_busqueda, respuesta.text

def procesar_resultados(html, palabra):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    resultados_encontrados = []
    bloque = soup.find_all("div", class_="g")
    for resultado in bloque:
        titulo = resultado.find('h3').string
        resultados_encontrados.append(titulo)
    return resultados_encontrados

def scrap(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
    palabra, html = obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
    resultados = procesar_resultados(html, palabra)
    return resultados

if __name__ == '__main__':
    palabra = 'Quantika14'
    h5 = (palabra, 1, "es")
h6 = (h5[0])

username=h6
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')



f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
title = f.find('a')['title']
print (title)

g=soup.find_all('title', limit=1)
h = soup.select('.bio',limit=1)



title2 =g
print (title2)
title3=h
print(title3)
```

Answer (score 0):

la opción mas fiable es usar el Api de Twitter, si bien es cierto tiene mucha información se puede acceder facílmente utilizando la librería pandas.

El siguiente ejemplo lo hicimos en un máster de BigData analizando a detalle palabra a palabra

Partiendo del ejemplo que puedas obtener a través del api la salida de tweets o cargarla dinamicamente prueba con esto

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("salida_tweets.txt", lines=True)

df.head(20)  // muestra primeras 20 lineas
df.columns   // obtiene los nombres de columnas
```

Resultado:

```
Index(['contributors', 'coordinates', 'created_at', 'delete', 'entities',
       'extended_entities', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'filter_level',
       'geo', 'id', 'id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name',
       'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str',
       'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'lang', 'place',
       'possibly_sensitive', 'retweet_count', 'retweeted', 'retweeted_status',
       'source', 'text', 'timestamp_ms', 'truncated', 'user'],
      dtype='object')
```

Obtenemos solo la columna texto de los tweets limitando a 30 filas

```
df["text"].head(30)
```

y si lo deseas puedes separar palabra a palabra del texto

```
    import json
    tweets = []

    tw = open("salida_tweets.txt")
for linea in tw:
    tweet_en_bruto = json.loads(linea)
    if 'text' in tweet_en_bruto.keys():
        tweets.append(tweet_en_bruto['text'].lower().split(" "))
```

Como se puede ver en el código anterior se han aplicado variasf funciones, en cada tweet, hemos escogido sólo la columna 'text' lo hemos descompuesto con split(" "), en palabras para poder ir buscando una a una en el archivo de sentimientos. Posteriormente, hemos forzado a que todos sean minúsculas, ya que si encontramos estas palabras "Hellow" y "hellow", en los tweetsAhora mostramos los Tweets descompuestos en espacios en una lista.

```
tweets[0:20]
```

Intentalo y ya me dices lo que sea, espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: pero yo no quiero extraer los tweets, lo que quiero es extraer un elemento concreto de la página de Twitter, que no los tweets. A ver, no lo que la gente escribe, sino el elemento donde está la descripción de la página de twitter.

Comment: $("[data-testid='UserDescription']").textContent   si está en el directorio de la página la idea es extraer esto con la sintaxis de BeautifulSoup, pero en ese punto me pierdo, eso es realmente lo que necesito.

Comment: He añadido modificaciones a la pregunta, puedes comprobarlo, tu respuesta no es lo que estoy preguntando.

Comment: Ya me he dado respuesta